# Swap Image with dropdown and add item to cart

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms, cart

I have a form dropdown menu that will change the image on my product page, but will not add selected item to my Mals-E cart. I can achieve either, but not both. I'm not much of a coder, so I'm not sure what to do. Seems I cannot have multiple names and values.

The form below changes the image as it is selected in the drop down.

HTML

```
<img name="myImage" src="https://sampleurl.com/image.jpg">

<div><form action="https://sampleurl/add.cfm" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="Hidden" name="return" value="https://www.sampleurl.com">
    <input type="Hidden" name="userid" value="sampleuserid">
    <input type="Hidden" name="thumb" value="sample.jpg">
                                  
<select onchange="switchImage();" class="dropdown" name="switch">
        <option value="0">Select Size</option>
        <option value="1">Product 1 - $100</option> 
        <option value="2">Product 1 - $200</option> 
        <option value="3">Product 1 - $300</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="submit, button" id="button">ADD TO CART</button>
</form></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var imageList = Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    imageList[i] = new Image(500, 500);
    imageList[i].src = "https://sampleurl.com/images/" + i + ".jpg";
}

function switchImage() {
    var selectedImage = document.myForm.switch.options[document.myForm.switch.selectedIndex].value;
    document.myImage.src = imageList[selectedImage].src;
}
```

As you can see below, these are the 'names' and 'values' I need to load the price info in to my Mals-E cart, but as you see above, the image swap needs the 'name' and 'value' as well.

Can these two options be fused so that I can swap the image and add info to the cart? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
<div><form action="https://sampleurl/add.cfm" method="post">
    <input type="Hidden" name="return" value="https://www.sampleurl.com">
    <input type="Hidden" name="userid" value="sampleuserid">
    <input type="Hidden" name="thumb" value="sample.jpg">
                 
<select name="productpr" size="1" class="dropdown">
        <option value="0">Select Size</option>
        <option value="Product 1:100.00">Product 1 - $100</option> 
        <option value="Product 1:200.00">Product 2 - $200</option> 
        <option value="Product 1:300.00">Product 3 - $300</option>
</select><br>

<button type="submit" class="submit, button" id="button">ADD TO CART</button>
</form></div>
```